# combobox on xpage to go to other page

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to put a combox on an xpages so the user can choose to witch page he wants to go.
for example if he chooses google he would go to google.com etc

I tried :

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Google"
                            itemValue="Google">
                        </xp:selectItem>
                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yahoo" itemValue="Yahoo"></xp:selectItem>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange"
                            submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var item = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();
if (item == 'Google') {
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
};
}]]>
</xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that item doesn't get any value. When I select an item from the combobox I get kind of message (translated) "The form doesn't contain an inputname $$viewid"

Comment: As Per suggests : one thing you can't do is mix CSJS and SSJS.  So that "window.location.href" has to go for sure.

Comment: correct, but how can I get the value of this combobox in SSJS ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing server-side Javascript with client-side Javascript.

Do this instead:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
   <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
     var item = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();
     if (item == 'Google') {
       facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://google.com");
     };
   }]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: you are right. But it seems that I can't get the value of the combox this way. I'm getting an error (see below)

Comment: It works for me (using your complete code with my changes). Perhaps you have disabled the form on the XPage itself using createForm="false"?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://example.com")
```

This and more things are available on xpagescheatsheet.com.  Note in addition to the printed cheatsheet there's a link to an online "URL Cheatsheet" that has a bunch or URL Examples.

Comment: The problem seems to be that item doesn't get any value. When I select an item from the combobox I get kind of message (translated) "The form doesn't contain an inputname $$viewid"

Answer (score 0):

Bind your combo to a document datasource field or to a scoped variable ?